# Why are my properties losing definition? (JS)

Tags: javascript, attributes, properties

I'm creating a drag/drop heavy page and giving each draggable element `defaultTop` and `defaultLeft` properties so that I can easily reset it to it's original position. This was fine and unremarkable until suddenly, the reset function reports their values as undefined. Since I wasn't working on these pieces when it broke (they've been working for some time) I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. Thanks for the help.

The function that creates the element is:

```
function makeTool(id, imgURL, defaultL, defaultT,trayname){
var a=document.createElement('img');
a.setAttribute('src', imgURL);
a.setAttribute('id',id);
a.setAttribute('class','drag');
a.intray=true;
a.tray=trayname;
a.rotation=0;
a.style.zIndex=document.getElementById(trayname).style.zIndex+1;
document.getElementById(trayname).appendChild(a);
a.defaultTop=ExtractNumber(document.getElementById(trayname).style.top)+defaultT;
a.defaultLeft=ExtractNumber(document.getElementById(trayname).style.left)+defaultL;
a.style.top=a.defaultTop+'px';
a.style.left =a.defaultLeft+'px';
a.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) { return self.touchStart(e) }, false);
a.addEventListener('gesturestart', function(e) { return self.gestureStart(e) }, false);
a.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) { return self.touchMove(e) }, false);
a.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) { return self.touchEnd(e) }, false);
tools.push(a);
return a;
}
```

and the reset function is:

```
function reposition(t){
    console.log(t+' top: '+document.getElementById(t).defaultTop);
    document.getElementById(t).style.left=document.getElementById(t).defaultLeft+'px';
    document.getElementById(t).style.top=document.getElementById(t).defaultTop+'px';
}
```

which is where I'm getting the log of `undefined`

Comment: Just of out interest: Why are you writing so much from scratch? Why not use a library like jQuery to do all the heavy lifting for you?

Comment: Mostly because I am learning as I go, and I haven't used jQuery in awhile, so it's not as much of a time saver as it might be otherwise

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log(a.defaultTop)` where `a.defaultTop` gets defined? Is it being assigned `undefined` from the start?

Comment: in your makeTool function log a.defaultTop value just after you set it. is it correctly defined there?

Comment: @Anton:Yes and no...I create n tools, then I looped through the tools array, logging the values, and they were set fine. But I haven't done the same while using document.getelementbyid. I'm on my phone now so can't immediately check, but I will. What really bothers me is that it used to work (and still does in iPad webapp, but not mobile safari)

Comment: I think we'd have to see enough code to see something that can actually run to know what's wrong.

Comment: @Robot Woods, I'd also suggest less DOM-oriented approach to work with tools, if it's an option. Store tools as normal objects, and reference corresponding DOM elements via attributes. Like `tool = {}; tool.el = document.createElement('img'); tool.intray = true;` and so on. Kinda seems more reliable to me.

Comment: I was concerned that element properties were different that object properties, so I'll give that a shot. I am under NDA with the client so can't post much more code without some scrubbing, but maybe that exercise will reveal the error. Thanks, I'll respond again in 8-9 hours

Comment: Well, it works now, but I'm still confused why it hadn't failed on the iPad: I modified it so that instead of referring directly to the image elements, it looks for the item in the tools array (a roundabout way of Anton's object suggestion, post as a solution and I'll accept). The properties seem to persist there, but not in the elements themselves. Technically it is an array of elements, but within the array they're behaving as objects. More to learn.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if thar helps, but I had a similar problem.

I was writing a object to calculate de width of my DIVs accordingly to my innerWidth:

```
function ScreenGrid() {
'use strict';

this.ColumnIDs = new Array();
this.Widths = new Array();
this.Dynamic = true;
this.Set = adjust;

var ColumnIDsPersist;
var WidthsPersist;

function adjust() {

    //stuff

    for (var i = 0; i < ColumnIDsPersist.length; i++) {
```

The adjust function is where de magic happends. To ensure that the DIVs would keep fitted in the screen I used the following code:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
            // Good browsers.
            window.addEventListener('resize', react, false);
        }
        else if (w.attachEvent) {
            // Legacy IE support.
            window.attachEvent('onresize', react);
        }
        else {
            // Old-school fallback.
            window.onresize = react;
        }
```

And this is the react function:

```
    // Slight delay.
function react() {

    // Clear the timer as window resize fires,
    // so that it only calls adapt() when the
    // user has finished resizing the window.
    clearTimeout(timer);

    // Start the timer countdown.
    timer = setTimeout(adjust, 16);
    // -----------------------^^
    // Note: 15.6 milliseconds is lowest "safe"
    // duration for setTimeout and setInterval.
    //
    // http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/12/14/timer-resolution-in-browsers
}
```

The problem was the every time REACT fires, o got undefined in this.ColumnIDs. After a lot o investigation i noticed that when I fired the ADJUST from SET() the object THIS was my SCREENGRID, but when I fired from REACT it becames the WINDOW, so I got undefined in this.ColumnIDs.

I solved with this code:

```
function ScreenGrid() {
'use strict';

this.ColumnIDs = new Array();
this.Widths = new Array();
this.Dynamic = true;
this.Set = adjust;

var ColumnIDsPersist;
var WidthsPersist;

function adjust() {

    // This clearTimeout is for IE.
    // Really it belongs in react(),
    // but doesn't do any harm here.
    clearTimeout(timer);

    // Parse browser width.
    var _width = window.innerWidth || window.document.documentElement.clientWidth || window.document.body.clientWidth || 0;
    var _heigth = window.innerHeight || window.document.documentElement.clientHeight || window.document.body.clientHeight || 0;
    var _usedWidth = 0;
    var _fluidColumn = null;


    //Ao chamar a função adjust novamente no evento on resize, o objeto THIS deixa de ser a função e passa a ser a janela,
    //Essas vareáveis garantem a persistencia dos dados a serem utilizados.
    ColumnIDsPersist = (typeof ColumnIDsPersist == 'undefined') ? this.ColumnIDs : ColumnIDsPersist;
    WidthsPersist = (typeof WidthsPersist == 'undefined') ? this.Widths : WidthsPersist;

    for (var i = 0; i < ColumnIDsPersist.length; i++) {
```

Well, that's it, I hope it helps!